# How to get the response of file in flask rest api python

Tags: python, rest, flask, file-upload, flask-restful

I have created a sample flask rest API to upload a file. The POST request is working fine I am able to see the uploaded file in the path which I specified in my program. But now I want to get the response of that pdf file as well in my program but I am stuck at this point how can I process the pdf file back to get all the data from that pdf file through GET request.
My code so far is:

```
 #app.py
from flask import Flask, json, request, jsonify
import os
import urllib.request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
 
UPLOAD_FOLDER = r'E:\Uploaded_Files'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
 
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
 
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
 
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return 'Homepage'
 
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
        resp = jsonify({'message' : 'No file part in the request'})
        resp.status_code = 400
        return resp
 
    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
     
    errors = {}
    success = False
     
    for file in files:      
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            success = True
        else:
            errors[file.filename] = 'File type is not allowed'
 
    if success and errors:
        errors['message'] = 'File(s) successfully uploaded'
        resp = jsonify(errors)
        resp.status_code = 500
        return resp
    if success:
        resp = jsonify({'message' : 'Files successfully uploaded'})
        resp.status_code = 201
        return resp
    else:
        resp = jsonify(errors)
        resp.status_code = 500
        return resp
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now how will I be able to get the data of that uploaded file back in response in the above program

Comment: Does that mean you want to read parts of the PDF? You would probably want a PDF library, like this one: https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

Comment: @mechanical_meat yes in GET response I want to get the response of the pdf file which I just uploaded. but How will I use that library in my code above can you please give me a sample code relative to my code above

Comment: How are you planning to identify the file that was just uploaded? Is there some logic for which PDF you want to read, for example, if there are multiple PDF files uploaded?

Comment: do you need filename in response? file object probably would have that attribute. if you need to open the file as response to an endpoint, i suggest using JavaScript.

Comment: @mechanical_meat there will always be only one file lets say at a time which I will be reading for the get response by giving the filename in the Get Api url considering my code above

Comment: @Henshal B I am looking to open the file/somehow extract the complete content of the file as a response. I am looking for a way to do it in flask rest api such as post request to upload a file and get request to get the content of that file. Although I can use that api in any client program. Can you please suggest me how will I do it by some code?

Comment: @Henshal B There could be two get methods one to get the information about file and other to get the content of the pdf file